# Generate child list

Tags: c#, .net, integration-testing, xunit, autofixture

I have the following two classes:

```
public class Blog
{
    public Blog()
    {
        Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; private set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Uri { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

I try to use AutoFixture to generate sample data which I'd like to use in my tests.

```
var blogs = new List<Blog>(new Fixture().Build<Blog>()
      .Without(x => x.BlogId)
      .CreateMany(10));
```

But the post's collection is null.

The question is how could I use Autofixture to generate Blog and corresponding posts, let's say 10 posts per every 10 blogs.

Comment: Because `Posts` property have private setter. _AutoFixture doesn't have built-in support for assigning values to non-public fields or properties. This is by design._

Answer (score 1):

> But the post's collection is null.

Not quite; the `Posts` collections are *empty*, because they're initialised to empty HashSets in the `Blog` constructor.

> how could I use Autofixture to generate Blog and corresponding posts

Use `fixture.AddManyTo` in a `Do` block:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var blogs = fixture.Build<Blog>()
    .Without(b => b.BlogId)
    .Do(b => fixture.AddManyTo(b.Posts, 10))
    .CreateMany(10);
```

This'll create 10 `Blog` objects, each with 10 `Post` objects in the `Posts` collection.